# gradle/intelij - not generating hibernate meta model classes?

Tags: hibernate, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, jpa-2.0

I am using inteliJ as IDE and Gradle as build tool.
Following this [article on MetamodelGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html) , I have configured annotation processor on intelij as suggested.

[image]

And my gradle file is as below. I have taken the `hibernate-jpamodelgen` artifact from [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-jpamodelgen/6.1.1.Final) as suggested. But still i don't see any Meta Model classes being generated in the build/generated folder or sub-folder.  How do i fix this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. This is a blocker for me.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
    ext {
        lombokVersion = '1.18.16'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.abc.reports'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"

    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.7.0'

    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.8.2")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17")

    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.1.1.Final'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

As suggest by @y-bedrov - i am already using gradle for `build and run`
[image]

Comment: Does it help to disable annotation processing? Seems similar to [IDEA-232367](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-232367/Annotation-processor-generates-source-code-on-auto-build-even-though-annotation-processing-is-disabled-in-Idea)

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov - thanks for reference. But no it does not work with annotation processing disabled either. I tried. Quite a blocker on my end. Is there any thing with the gradle file that i can fix.

Comment: Please try to set "Intellij IDEA" in "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle - Build and Run using"

Comment: @y.bedrov - i updated the Q. I am already using Gradle for `Build and Run`

Comment: I see. Will it help to switch to Intellij IDEA for build action?

Comment: @y.bedrov - sorry i did not get what you meant. can you elaborate.

Comment: Currently you have "Gradle" selected in "Build and Run using" field. Please try to select "Intellij Idea" there.

Comment: tried.. no luck. Thanks for involvement +1

Comment: Are the model classes generated if you build by Gradel from the command line? if not, this looks like the Gradle is not properly configured for the annotation processing.